# Is it possible to show checked radio button if we returned to the url?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, spring-thymeleaf

I have 2 views: 1view: some radio buttons to choose from, 2view: based on the radio button display some data. In the 2 view I can return to the first view but how can I show the **chosen** radio button previously?
Naive idea: access parameters from URL. This is what I chose but did not work. Code below of the 1 view:

```
<main class="general">
    <h2>Games</h2>
        <form action="/reservations/chooseGame" method="post">
            <div class="container">
                <p th:if="${games.empty}" >No Games Available.</p>
                <p th:each="game : ${games}">
                    <input id="gameId" type="radio" name="gameId" th:value="${game.id}" th:checked="${game.id == gameId or param.gameId == game.id}" th:disabled="${checkButton == null}" th:hidden="${checkButton == null}" required/>
                    <label for="gameId" class="label-rad">
                        <span th:text="${game.name}"></span>
                    </label>
                </p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" th:hidden="${checkButton == null}">Submit</button>
            <a th:href="@{/reservations/1}" th:hidden="${checkButton == null}" class="button-back">Go Back</a>
        </form>
</main>
```

**param.gameId** is from url. url: http://localhost:8080/reservations/chooseGame?gameId=1

But why it didn’t check the radio button if everything was present?

Comment: @Unmitigated unfortunately didn’t help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the id to a string, then use `#strings.equals` to compare.

```
#strings.equals(param.gameId, #strings.toString(game.id))
```